# configuring Nagios with check_by_ssh

Tags: ssh, nagios

I am trying to configure Nagios to use "**check_by_ssh**" plugin, to monitor if the service "**mpg123**" is running on a remote Linux computer.

- I have Configured passwordless login between Nagios server & client
- Defined the command to check if the process is running.

**/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/check_music.cfg**

```
define command {
        command_name    check_music
        command_line    $USER1$/check_by_ssh -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C "pgrep mpg123 > /dev/null && echo YES || echo NO"
}
```

- Created the host definition file

**/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/client002.cfg**

```
define host{
        use                     linux-server
        host_name               client002
        alias                   Client002
        address                 192.168.1.52
        }    

define service{
        use                    generic-service
        host_name              client002
        service_description    Music
        check_command          check_music
        }
```

- Configured Nagios to know where to look for these files

**/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg**

```
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/client002.cfg
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/check_music.cfg
```

My problem is that under Services in Nagios, I get a message saying:

```
Remote command execution failed: Could not create directory '/home/nagios/.ssh'.
```

Comment: For which user did you configure the passwordless SSH? From the output it seems the user `nagios` is trying to connect via SSH. Normally you have service user that can be specified with `-l`option to the `check_by_ssh` plugin. Additionally the service user needs approriate access rights on the client.